# Are Mafia 3 saves backed-up to the Cloud/How do I manually back-up my saves?

Tags: pc, mafia-3

For Mafia 3 on PC (Steam), when I exit the game, I notice that there is no Cloud upload. Does that mean the saves are just local, like Just Cause 3? Is there a way to back them up manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this thread](http://steamcommunity.com/app/360430/discussions/0/343788552537672857/):

> savegames are only saved locally.
>
> X:/User/x/appdata/2kgames/mafia3

And based on [this post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/360430/discussions/0/343788552544824074/):

> Is there any chance of cloud saves being implemented anytime soon?

And [this post](http://steamcommunity.com/app/360430/discussions/0/343788552549653718/), which pleads for the addition of cloud saves:

> Please add cloud saves so the game can be continued from where you left off and played properly.

As well as [this post](http://steamcommunity.com/app/360430/discussions/0/343788552536455571/), which acknowledges the lack of a cloud save feature:

> As far as I'm aware, the game doesn't have Steam Cloud support

So for the first part of your question, **yes, the game is only saved locally.**

---

However, you are able to manually back them up [this way](http://steamcommunity.com/app/360430/discussions/0/343788552549653718/):

> Heres a method to copy the savegame to your other pc manually, in case you want that as a temporary solution.
>
> go here C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\2K Games\Mafia III
>
> (Replace X with your windows username)
>
> copy the 2 folders to a usb, and bring it to your other pc and copy it back.

Answer (score -2):

In order to find the local saves, you'll want to open Windows Explorer to the following location:

C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\2K Games

Comment: nope, at least not for Win10x64 1607